# Select values on one column having an identical set of values on another column

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, mariadb

I have a "relational table" that stores which post has which tags. Just like Stack Overflow, a post can have many tags, and a tag can have many posts.

The table only has two columns and it looks like this:

```
pid tid

1   3
1   4

2   1
2   3
2   4

3   1
3   3
3   4

4   1
4   3

5   1
5   3

6   2
6   4
```

In the above table, post 2 and 3 have an identical set of tags (values on another column `tid`), and so are post 4 and 5.

I want to select all posts (post IDs) where there exists another post with the same set of `tid`, so the query should return `2 3 4 5` from column `pid`.

I'm running on MariaDB 10.1.38.

Here's my own attempt but apparently it fails:

```
SELECT p.pid
FROM post_tags AS p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM post_tags AS p2
    WHERE
      GROUP_CONCAT(p.tid SEPARATOR ',') = GROUP_CONCAT(p2.tid SEPARATOR ',')
    GROUP BY p2.pid
  )
GROUP BY p.pid;
```

MariaDB told me:

> ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` is an aggregate function, so you can't apply it in the `WHERE` clause, as it's evaluated in the `SELECT` clause (this happens after `WHERE`).

Also note, that you should add an `ORDER BY` in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function. There's no guaranteed order in a relational database, unless you specifically specify it.

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT t1.pid FROM 
(
    SELECT
    pid, GROUP_CONCAT(tid ORDER BY tid) AS gctid
    FROM t t1
    GROUP BY pid
) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT
    pid, GROUP_CONCAT(tid ORDER BY tid) AS gctid
    FROM t t1
    GROUP BY pid
) t2 ON t1.pid != t2.pid AND t1.gctid = t2.gctid
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cb460/2/0)